# Change name of aar file from Kotlin Multiplatform build

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kotlin multiplatform project that I am trying to publish to my `Jetbrains Space` maven repo. It successfully publishes to the repo but the name of the artifact is the name of my module  in the project which is not the name as what the project is called.

example the published artifact is

> com.tycz:sharedmodule-android:0.2.0

but I want it to be something like

> com.tycz:myLibrary-android:0.2.0

I am using these [doc's](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-publish-lib.html) as reference

This is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("maven-publish")
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

group = "com.tycz"
version = "0.2.0"

kotlin {
    android{
        publishLibraryVariants("release")
    }
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "sharedmodule"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.4.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:1.4.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:1.4.1")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.4.1")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.12")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:1.4.1")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        excludes.add("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/tyczj/p/vqi18/tweedle")
                credentials {
                    username = "$username"
                    password = "$password"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework =
        kotlin.targets.getByName<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget>(
            targetName
        ).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

How can I change the name of the artifact?

Answer (score 0):

to change the module name will solve your question

before

```
include(":android", ":desktop", ":common")
```

after

```
include(":android", ":desktop", ":youlib")
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, `maven-publish` plugin derives artifactId from the `Project`'s `name` attribute([link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:identity_values_in_the_generated_pom)), so to change the artifact's name I would recommend setting the appropriate name at your module's `settings.gradle.kts` like that:

```
rootProject.name = 'myLibrary'
```